# Changing the order of a selected part of the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am writing a class `Deck` for an assignment. The class that takes an array of codes each representing a card like 3D(3 of Diamonds), 5S(5 of Spades), As(Ace of spades) and if the last letter representing the type of card is in lower case, then it means that the card is turned over. `toString()` returns a string of the given deck, if the cards are facing upwards, it is added to the string, but if the card is turned over, then it adds ** to the string so:

```
>>const deck1 = new Deck(["ah", "3S", "KC", "4H", "3D", "10H", "8D", "5D", "7C", "QS"]);
>>deck1.toString();
"** 3S KC 4H 3D 10H 8D 5D 7C QS"
```

`turn(arr)` takes an optional array or number and turns those cards over. If no argument is given, it turns every card, if an empty array is given, it changes nothing.

The function I'm trying to write, `turnTop(num)` takes an int draws that many card from the deck and puts each card turned over in reverse order. So:

```
>>const deck1 = new Deck(["ah", "3S", "KC", "4H", "3D", "10H", "8D", "5D", "7C", "QS"]);
>>deck1.turnTop(3);
"** ** AH 4H 3D 10H 8D 5D 7C QS" // "ah" was first, now AH is the third card
```

I can turn the cards but I couldn't find a way to reverse the ordering of the affected cards.

```
class Deck{
     constructor(deck) {
    this.deck = deck;
    const digit = /\d/;
    const type = /[2-9AKQJakqj]/; // Ace, King, Queen, Joker
    const color = /[CDHScdhs]/;
    for (let card of deck) {
        if (digit.test(card.charAt(card.length - 1))) {
            throw "AssertionError: invalid card";
        } else if (!type.test(card.charAt(0))) {
            if (card.charAt(1) !== "0") { // as not to throw an error if the card is  is 10
                throw "AssertionError: invalid card";
            }
        } else if (!color.test(card.charAt(card.length - 1))) {
            throw "AssertionError: invalid card";
        }
    }
}
    toString(){
        let str = "";
        for (let card of this.deck){
            if (card.charAt(card.length-1) === card.charAt(card.length-1).toUpperCase()){
                str += " " + card;
            }
            else if(card.charAt(card.length-1) === card.charAt(card.length-1).toLowerCase()){
                str += " " + "**"
            }
        }
        str = str.substring(1);
        return str;
    }
    turn(arr){
        if (arr === undefined ){
            for (let i in this.deck){
                if(this.deck[i].charAt(this.deck[i].length-1) === this.deck[i].charAt(this.deck[i].length-1).toUpperCase() ){
                    this.deck[i] = this.deck[i].toLowerCase();
                }else{
                    this.deck[i] = this.deck[i].toUpperCase();
                }
            }
        }else if (arr.length > 1){
            for (let card of arr){
                if (this.deck[card - 1] === this.deck[card - 1].toUpperCase()){
                    this.deck[card - 1] =  this.deck[card - 1].toLowerCase();
                }else{
                    this.deck[card - 1] =  this.deck[card - 1].toUpperCase();
                }
            }
        }else if(arr.length === 0){
            return new Deck(this.deck);
        }
        else{
            if (this.deck[arr-1] === this.deck[arr-1].toUpperCase()){
                this.deck[arr-1] = this.deck[arr-1].toLowerCase();
            }else{
                this.deck[arr-1] = this.deck[arr-1].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        return new Deck(this.deck);
    }

    turnTop(num){
        for (let i =1;i<=num;i++){
            if ((this.deck[i-1] === this.deck[i-1].toUpperCase())){
                this.deck[i-1] = this.deck[i-1].toLowerCase();
            }else{
                this.deck[i-1] = this.deck[i-1].toUpperCase();
            }
        }return new Deck(this.deck);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to select `n` amount of first cards, reverse them in order and put them back in the deck at the start?

Comment: Yes, draw n cards from the top, then put them back on top of the deck in the same drawing order but turned over. Last drawn card is now at the top. So turn(2) : A B C D E => b a C D E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method on the array of cards to get a "slice" from the array and use the [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method to reverse the order. Then get the rest of the cards with another slice and concatenate both slices back together.

And to check for the upper or lower case check use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with either capitalized or lowercase letters.

```js
const cards = ["AH", "3S", "KC", "4H", "3D", "10H", "8D", "5D", "7C", "QS"];

class Deck {

  constructor(cards) {
    this.deck = cards;
  }

  turnTop(amount) {
    let cardSelection = this.deck.slice(0, amount).reverse().map(card => {
      if (card.toLowerCase() === card) {
        return card.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        return card.toLowerCase();
      }
    });
    let restOfCards = this.deck.slice(amount, this.deck.length);
    this.deck = [...cardSelection, ...restOfCards];
    return this;
  }
  
}

const deckOfCards = new Deck(cards);
deckOfCards.turnTop(3);

console.log(deckOfCards.deck);
```